# Raw_input() & input() react differently in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

I have tried two versions of this code and both end up giving me different results. Is there a reason why?

Raw_input() makes the program get into an infinite loop; 
input() works normally

```
numbers = []
increments = 1

def loop(i, dial):
    while i < dial:
        print "At the top i is %d" % i
        numbers.append(i)

        i += increments
        print "Numbers now: ", numbers
        print "At the bottom i is %d" % i
    return

dial = raw_input('What is dial?  ') # -Code goes berserck
#OR **dial = input('What is dial?  ') -Code acts normal
loop(0, dial)
```

Comment: They are completely different in 2.7 per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html).

Comment: `input()` is the function you want to avoid in Python 2; use `raw_input()` and do a proper conversion (to integer in your case).

Comment: Furthermore, your `dial` variable is a `str`. So of course your `while` will never evaluate for termination.

Comment: What you could have done before asking is enter `help(input)` and `help(raw_input)` at an interactive prompt.  Or you could have looked up both in the index of the docs.  Learn to use both `help` and the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

**BLUF**: Don't use `input` in Python 2.7 when requesting user input. Use `raw_input` then the appropriate cast (`int()`, `float()`, etc...) on the variable storing the user input.

Quick breakdown of whats going on here in Python 2.7:

- `raw_input()` returns a `str` (i.e. 'hello world')
- `input()` is a wrapper for `eval(raw_input())` which tries to figure out what the `str` represents. **Don't use this to solve your problem.**

So that gives you the following if I input `24`:

```
dial = raw_input('Dial: ') # '24'
dial = input('Dial: ') # 24
```

The latter is "`eval`-uated" to an `int` so thus your `while` will terminate. Otherwise, the former is trying to compare an `int` to see if it is less than a `str` which will never terminate.

What you need to do: `dial = int(raw_input('Dial: '))`.

Comment: I see! Thanks for the answer, helped a bunch!

Comment: @pstatix: I can guess the reason for the downvotes: As written, your answer seems like it's encouraging people to use `eval` (or `input`) instead of suggesting a more specific (and safer) conversion like `int`. (I didn't downvote, but I did retract my upvote after realizing that.)

Comment: @abarnert Very silly reason for somebody to downvote. I've not said to use `eval` (or `input`).  I've simply explained *why* the OP's code isnt working based upon their snippet!

Comment: @pstatix Trying to understand the reasons behind downvotes is hard enough; trying to understand why people think those are good reasons is beyond me. I stopped worrying about scores years ago, beyond making me briefly consider whether to expand or rewrite. (And, frankly, if you've seen the length of most of my answers, all that expanding may not be a good thing…)

Answer (score 0):

`input()` will evaluate the user's input. So, if I typed 5 as the user input, `input()` will let python know that the user input `5` is in fact an interger.

`raw_input()` will not do this. It will take whatever the user input is and make it into a string. So the user input `5` will acutally be `"5"` if you use `raw_input()`.

Answer (score -1):

- **`input()`**: Interprets and evaluates the input which means that if user enters integer, an integer will be returned, if user enters string,string is returned.
- **`raw_input()`:** `raw_input()` takes exactly what user typed and passes it back as string. It doesn’t interprets the user input.Even an integer value of 10 is entered or a list is entered its type will be of string only.

Comment: Gotcha! all clear now, 
Thank you, much appreciated!